# 404 custom error page redirects to a blank white for .html pages

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have made custom error page on asp.net and it works good only for .aspx pages
For .htm pages it redirects to a blank page. Help please, a have no strength any more((

This is my code in Global.asax -

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if (ex is HttpException)
            {
                if (((HttpException)(ex)).GetHttpCode() == 404)

                    Server.Transfer("~/error404.htm");
            }
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            string err = "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                              ". Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString();
            Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
        }
```

and in Web.config -

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error404.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

and -

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/error404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

HELP!!(( Thanks!

Comment: Looks a lot like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648007/iis7-custom-404-not-showing, does the configuration they suggest there help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above configuration applies to requests processed by the asp.net pipeline.  Unless you have .html files mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll, none of this configuration is relevant.

You can configure the server to redirect 404s to your custom page, but that is at the IIS level, not the asp.net level.

Comment: Thank you very much! So this issue just with IIS properties?

Comment: Yes, in the IIS console, you can configure the 404 error page

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect with the following syntax:

```
Server.Transfer(@".\error404.htm");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect(@".\error404.htm");
```