# How to make ASP.NET process all possible file extensions so it can be captured in a custom error page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've setup custom errors and it's working,
But in some cases IIS does not recognize the file extension and therefore does not even process the page...

For example: 
http://example-web-site.com/page.aaa

So, ".aaa" is not recognized and IIS shows an ugly error page
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How can I handle all (unknown extensions) so I can still capture every hit to the web site and do something with it or show my custom error page?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648007/iis7-custom-404-not-showing/6661699#6661699

Comment: I think this would be better asked on serverfault or webmasters.

Comment: I'd really advertise against allowing all extensions.. It's a potential big security risk. Register just the file extensions you know and need (it's called whitelisting btw).

Comment: I don't really want to process these extensions, just to be able to have everything hit my app on IIS so I can decide what to do with it... maybe it can be done using the IIS rewrite module...