# Hot to show custom page not found page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

My URL is like http://app.test.com/asp/default.aspx

When user mis types URL like http://app.test.com/asp/defaul123t.aspx and hits i am redirecting to custom error page pagenotfound.html.
For this i made changes in

> INETMGR-->Websites-->Defaultwebsite-->Mywebsite-->Properties-->CustomErrors--> For HTTP Error 400

I set the file path for `pagenotfound.html`

But my problem is when user mistypes URL like http://app.test.com/asp/www.google.com 
I am not getting redirected to custom page not found page `pagenotfound.html`

instead it is showing internet explorer http404 page

> The page cannot be found
>   The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Please help me in resolving the same.

Comment: Actually 400 and 404 are different HTTP status codes, if you want to redirect to pagenotfound.html you should set custom error for both. Difference is _who_ (IIS/ASP.NET) returns 404 error. Check also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/667053/1207195).

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS7 custom 404 not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648007/iis7-custom-404-not-showing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to try like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/YourErrorPage.aspx">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Also check **[`<customErrors>` Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx)** and [Displaying a Custom Error Page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Comment: I have the below code already in web.config file.<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/pagenotfound.html" >
      <error statusCode ="404" redirect="~/pagenotfound.html"/>
      <error statusCode ="400" redirect="~/pagenotfound.html"/>
    </customErrors>