# Custom error page not working in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I have implemented custom 404 page in my ASP. NET MVC 5 application, at first I have tested it on my localhost, and it worked perfectly. But when I moved my settings to release config, and tried to test it in production, the custom 404 page was gone, there was default mvc error page. What did I do wrong?

**Web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Index" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

        Response.StatusCode = 404;

        return View("~/Views/..../Index.cshtml", vm);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I am running Windows Server 2012 R2, so it should be IIS 8.5

Comment: I am looking into this thing, meanwhile I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648007/iis7-custom-404-not-showing) link, can you try this out?

Comment: I have tried it, only thing that works is removing the httpErrors from transofrmation and keep it in base web.cofing file. I do not know why this is working, I have compared the transformated file with version that has 404 handling in base web.config and they are the same.

Comment: Which web server are you using on your localhost? Cassini, IISExpress or IIS? And which version? In my experience, IIS httpErrors `ExecuteURL` mode is unable to go through MVC routing, causing the result you have on your server. But maybe have you some specific configuration (module execution order?) on your localhost allowing to solve this trouble. It could be very interesting for me if you could identify it.

Comment: Maybe should you check if the infamous [rammfar (`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`)](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) is active on your localhost. But avoid using that for "solving" the trouble, if it does.

Answer (score 2):

I remember it has to be set under the `<system.web>`. This is how it should be.

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/Index" />
</customErrors>
```

So setting the `mode="Off"` and `mode="On"` will toggle the Custom Error page on and off.

Comment: `customErrors` and `httpErrors` are two different beasts. [`customErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) handles .Net failures error pages, while [`httpErrors`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) applies to IIS default error pages. `customErrors` does not cover cases which does not involve a .Net pipeline, like requests on static resources.

Comment: @Frédéric EXCELENT!!! As a wrong page I was testing `Default.aspx1` that did not involve a .Net pipeline.  Your comment was the only thing that could save my life!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to config file

```
<customErrors mode ="on" defaultRedirect="">

</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.
The code was working in Dev and not in Prod.

Just remove the line

```
Response.StatusCode = 404; //REMOVE
```

from the action method. It will work.