# Umbraco application custom error redirect works for 500 status, but not for 404

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

In my umbraco application I have created error page and then defined in web.config custom error redirect to that page in case of failure like this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error" />
```

It works fine in case application returns status 500, but if user wants to access not existing page then redirect does not happen. I even try to specifically define redirect for 404 status like this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

but still without a success.

Comment: You may try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661699/1273882

Comment: Thank you very much! I have actually found this one myself and tried it, without a success though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in umbracoSettings.config. The default version of the file contained following rule definition:

```
<errors>
  <error404>1</error404>
</errors>
```

It seemingly has overridden the rule defined in web.config and in case of 404 status redirected to page with id "1". Removing the line with error404 everything works as expected:

```
<errors></errors>
```